# The possibility of rapidly changing the Earths orbit via a passing astronomical object

Tags: orbit, gravity, orbital-elements, celestial-mechanics, tidal-forces

I assume that the Earth could be “gently” (without colossal tidal or volcanic catastrophe) displaced by a passing extra solar star, brown dwarf or planet and end up perhaps 10% further away from the Sun?

If so how quickly could this be achieved?

I suppose it would depend on the details, but roughly what combination of distance of approach and mass of object would be best to use for use in a realistic fictional setting? incidentally I assume the orbits of outer planets might well be much more badly affected.

Comment: Are you asking if the earth can be moved to another orbit without destroying life as we know it?

Comment: I'm fairly certain that it could, although I stand to be corrected. I'm really asking how quickly this could be achieved without destroying life as we know it.